# C# Using X Y coords to size from CopyFromScreen doesn't capture the entire width of image

Tags: c#, crop

What I'm basically trying to do is take a screen shot and capture a specific portion of the page using two sets of x/y cords.  When I use both cords however, the width of the image is not matching what is expected.   I've verified that the x/y cords for both sets are exactly what I want, however the image size is wrong and is missing some of the cords that I want to have a screen shot for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CropTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testDir = @"C:\test";
            string testFile = Path.Combine(testDir, $"test.png");
            int startX = 5;
            int startY = 50;
            int endX = 115;
            int endY = 150;
            SaveScreenshot(Screen.PrimaryScreen, testFile, startX, startY, endX, endY);

        }

        public static void SaveScreenshot(Screen screen, string file, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
        {
            Rectangle rect = ScreenResolutionHandler.GetRealRectangle(screen);
            int x = rect.X;
            int y = rect.Y;
            int w = rect.Width;
            int h = rect.Height;

            int newWidth = endX - startX;
            int newHeight = endY - startY;

            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(w, h))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(startX, startY, 0, 0, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
                    //g.CopyFromScreen(sourceX, sourceY, 0, 0, new Size(destX-sourceX, destY-sourceY), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                }
                if (File.Exists(file))
                    File.Delete(file);
                bitmap.Save(file);
            }
            string origDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
            string origFileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            file = Path.Combine(origDir, "orig_" + origFileName);

            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(w, h))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(startX, startY, 0, 0, new Size(w, h));
                    //g.CopyFromScreen(sourceX, sourceY, 0, 0, new Size(destX-sourceX, destY-sourceY), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                }
                if (File.Exists(file))
                    File.Delete(file);
                bitmap.Save(file);
            }
        }
    }

    class ScreenResolutionHandler
    {
        const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
        public static Rectangle GetRealRectangle(Screen screen)
        {
            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DEVMODE));
            EnumDisplaySettings(screen.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm);
            return new Rectangle(dm.dmPositionX, dm.dmPositionY, dm.dmPelsWidth, dm.dmPelsHeight);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DEVMODE
        {
            private const int CCHDEVICENAME = 0x20;
            private const int CCHFORMNAME = 0x20;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
            public string dmDeviceName;
            public short dmSpecVersion;
            public short dmDriverVersion;
            public short dmSize;
            public short dmDriverExtra;
            public int dmFields;
            public int dmPositionX;
            public int dmPositionY;
            public ScreenOrientation dmDisplayOrientation;
            public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;
            public short dmColor;
            public short dmDuplex;
            public short dmYResolution;
            public short dmTTOption;
            public short dmCollate;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
            public string dmFormName;
            public short dmLogPixels;
            public int dmBitsPerPel;
            public int dmPelsWidth;
            public int dmPelsHeight;
            public int dmDisplayFlags;
            public int dmDisplayFrequency;
            public int dmICMMethod;
            public int dmICMIntent;
            public int dmMediaType;
            public int dmDitherType;
            public int dmReserved1;
            public int dmReserved2;
            public int dmPanningWidth;
            public int dmPanningHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Full screen capture.

[image: Full Screen shot]

Result.

[image: Code Result]

Expected result.

[image: Expected]